# linq how to access variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am very new to using linq. My aim is to elements (vector3s) of a list that has a property x and z and want to find the average of 2 vector3 elements who x or z values are the same. For example say if you had a floor and it had 4 vertices  a,b,c,d where a is the topleft corner, b is the topright corner, c is the bottom left corner, d is the bottom right corner. I would like to find the mid points between ab, cd, bd, ac. I actually have a dictionary where a gameobject floor has a corresponding vertices in a vector3 list. This would explain my code so far.

```
Dictionary<GameObject, List<Vector3>> floorVertices = new Dictionary<GameObject, List<Vector3>>();
List<Vector3> vertices = new List<Vector3>();

verticeMidpoints = (
        from l in floorVertices.Values 
        from v in l 
        where l.Any(v2 => v2.x == v.x || v2.z == v.z) 
        select (new Vector3((v.x + v2.x) / 2), 
                            (v.y + v2.y) / 2, 
                            (v.z + v2.z) / 2);
    ).ToList();
```

Heres the code to find the vertices.

```
// the floor has 8 vertices and I would like the bottom ones that touch the ground
vertices = (
        from v in vertices 
        where v.y < ((  from v2 in vertices 
                        select v2.y
                      ).Average()) 
        select v
    ).ToList();
```

How would I adjust (where v2 cannot be accessed)

```
verticeMidpoints = (
        from l in floorVertices.Values 
        from v in l 
        where l.Any(v2 => v2.x == v.x || v2.z == v.z) 
        select (new Vector3((v.x + v2.x) / 2), 
                            (v.y + v2.y) / 2, 
                            (v.z + v2.z) / 2)
    ).ToList();
```

to make it work.

and Im pretty sure the code to find the vertices has more code to then needed.
Please help

Comment: There so much linq. Please remember that this is used in Unity where frame-rate and memory allocation matters so much more than a normal C# application.Avoid doing all these with linq. Build a an extension method that can do this with a `for` loop.

Comment: @Programmer LINQ is faster than most people give it credit for. A well-designed LINQ query can be just as fast as an equivalent for/foreach loop. (And in some cases, even faster.)

Comment: That being said, I do have to agree that you shouldn't be using LINQ in a gaming environment unless you know what you're doing, as a *poorly*-designed LINQ query can cripple frame rates.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in the comments, a well-designed LINQ query can make code clean and concise with little or no impact to performance, but unless you are confident in your LINQ knowledge, you should avoid it wherever possible when execution speed is a major concern (as it is for game programming).

Instead, you should use helper methods and regular loops to get what you're after:

*Getting Vertices:*

```
public List<Vector3> GetFloorVertices(List<Vector3> vertices)
{
    // Preallocate memory for the list so we don't 
    // need to worry about reallocating on insertions
    List<Vector3> floorVerts = new List<Vector3>(vertices.Count);
    float avg = vertices.Average(v => v.y);

    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Count; i++)
    {
        if (vertices[i].y < avg)
        {
            floorVerts.Add(vertices[i]);
        }
    }

    return floorVerts;
}
```

*Getting Midpoints:*

```
public List<Vector3> GetMidpoints(List<Vector3> vertices)
{
    // Preallocate memory for the list so we don't 
    // need to worry about reallocating on insertions
    List<Vector3> midpoints = new List<Vector3>(vertices.Count * vertices.Count);

    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < vertices.Count; j++)
        {
            if (vertices[i].x != vertices[j].x && vertices[i].z != vertices[j].z)
                continue;

            midpoints.Add(new Vector3(
                            (vertices[i].x + vertices[j].x) / 2,
                            (vertices[i].y + vertices[j].y) / 2,
                            (vertices[i].z + vertices[j].z) / 2
            ));
        }
    }

    return midpoints;
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply I threw in a foreach statement for multiple floor and I get an error Dictionary<GameObject, List<Vector3>> verticeMidpoints = new Dictionary<GameObject, List<Vector3>>();

            foreach (GameObject checkFloor in floorVertices.Keys)

Comment: verticeMidpoints.Add(checkFloor, new Vector3(
                                        (floorVertices[checkFloor][i].x + floorVertices[checkFloor][j].x) / 2,
                                        (floorVertices[checkFloor][i].y + floorVertices[checkFloor][j].y) / 2,
                                        (floorVertices[checkFloor][i].z + floorVertices[checkFloor][j].z) / 2

Comment: ah dont worry I just had a mind blank and leaped to help too quick. the error is converting from vector3 to vector3 lists

Comment: @user7688554 That'd be because you're adding a `new Vector3` to `verticeMidpoints` when you defined it as accepting a `List<Vector3>`.

Comment: hey abion, I've wrote this script.         Ray findMousePositionInGame = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        Physics.Raycast(findMousePositionInGame, out hit);                               
        mouseFloorPosition = new Vector3(hit.point.x, hit.point.y, hit.point.z);

Comment: I would like to find the closest midpoint to mouseFloorPosition to make things efficient, would you be able to help?

Comment: @user7688554 You could do something like `var closest = midpoints.Min(v => (v - mouseFloorPosition).sqrMagnitude);` (You don't need the actual distance as you're only finding the closest point, so using distance-squared/magnitude-squared will save you a costly `Mathf.Sqrt` call.)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [let](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) clause

so something like this

`verticeMidpoints = (
    from l in floorVertices.Values 
    from v in l 
    let v2 = 
    .......
).ToList();`

Comment: I will probably use the other due to performance reasons but for peace of mind.. how would I return the value from                                                                                                                             let v2 = l.Any(v2 => v2.x == v.x || v2.z == v.z)

Comment: When using "let" clause you need to operate on what's already available to you, i.e. based on earlier from/select. Basically "let" works as a temp variable to store some intermediate result/projection.